# Removing top margin of enumerate environment inside tabular cell

Tags: tables, xetex, margins, enumitem

I'm trying to set a itemized list inside a tabular cell without any margins.
I succeeded at removing (or resetting, respectively) the left margin but I can't seem to get rid of the top one (between "ONE" and "asdksdf").

Here's the MWP:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{0.4\textwidth}|} 
\hline
asdksdf\\
\hline
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0pt,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,noitemsep,nolistsep,partopsep=0pt]
  \item ONE
  \item TWO
\end{enumerate}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Which results in this output when using xelatex on MacOS:

[image: Output of MWP]

How do I get rid of the additional margin at the top of the table cell?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for adding a minimal document to your question. There doesn't seem to be a completely general solution to this problem, but the linked question provides what I think is the most elegant solution to the problem.

Comment: Thank you, the linked question addresses my issue.